# Recover a deleted repository github issues

Tags: github, recovery

My repository in the github had been deleted.
The code was recovered, but we had a lot of Github issues i'd like to recover, is there a way to recover them once deleted?

Thanks.

Comment: Your best bet would be speak to Github directly.

Comment: thanks, did it already, waiting for a reply

Comment: Well I doubt anyone else can give you much more insight into this.

Comment: If someone already did it, and will have good advice of actions i need to perform / avoid, it would be great.

Comment: Hi, Adibe7 Today it happens for me. can you advise what is solution for that.

Answer (score 70):

You need to email `support@github.com` as soon as possible when this happens.

Comment: Thanks Paul!  You just made our day today!  support@github.com was able to undo our delete.

Comment: This answer is still applicable, mine was restored within two minutes.

Comment: I am still waiting for 1 day. no response from support

Answer (score 40):

I accidentally deleted our main GitHub repository instead of my own fork. I emailed `support@github.com` like [Paul Betts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9256871/3974427) suggested.

After about **10 minutes** the support replied and the original repository was recovered.

Answer (score 3):

I accidentally deleted my important repository and when tried the above-suggested methods, got to know that the process has been updated.

Please follow the steps provided in the link to recover the repository all by yourself.
Link - https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/restoring-a-deleted-repository

**Note** - You can only restore repositories that have no forks or have not been forked. (As per mentioned under Settings >> Repositories >> Deleted Repositories section)

Also, for any Github-related support requests, one needs to raise the support request through Github's support website.
Link - https://support.github.com/ (works for any GitHub related support)

Answer (score 0):

The email approach is no longer working.

Now is required that new support requests be created using GitHub's support website: https://support.github.com

For **restoring deleted data** use this link: https://support.github.com/contact?tags=rr-restore