# Is there a way to restore github issues reported by me on a public repository after the issue section has been removed?

Tags: github, issue-tracking, github-issues

Recently we discovered that an opensource SSO solution which we were contributing to, through issue reporting, and we were using on our production, completely **removed the issues section** from github.

This means that any issues on which we were involved or we were using as part of our knowledge base are **not anymore accessible.**

We are currently using this solution on our production systems and the selection of it was heavily based on the **confidence that we gained from the presence of the above knowledge base**.

First we ensured that we have **answers, workarounds and configuration guidelines** for any possible issues that were facing and then we **selected it for production**. But even while on production we provided our technical feedback which we did not bother copying to some other place.

The issue that we currently face is that this **confidence has been lost**.  We have lost part of the module's documentation while the technology is on **production** which makes our application fragile to changes or even to bug-fixing.

**My questions are:**

- Is there a way to **re-gain access to these issues on github**, or at least the ones reported by us?
- Are there any **best practices** (e.g. tools/techniques) that we should follow in the future for making sure that we will never loose again this information, from a github-hosted public project? (e.g. are there tools that can keep backups of github issues section.)
- Are there any alternative repository hosting solutions that **could have prevented this unpleasant situation from happening**?

Comment: Hi, it seems like this question was asked before as well https://stackoverflow.com/q/9247961/10720730
and here is a reference for backup of github issues https://www.backhub.co/blog/three-ways-to-backup-your-github-issues

Comment: @Danish Not sure if it is the same question. In our case the repository does not belong to us. The repository owner decided to remove the issues section from the specific repository. The result of this was that we lost our contributions in this section. These contributions were part of our knowledge base and confidence for using this library on production.